# sp_helptext permission

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-grant

I need to give `sp_helptext` permission to the developers so that they can check the store procedures. Can somebody please, let me know how can i do it.

Thanks,
Christine

Answer (score 5):

I think `grant execute on sp_helptext` is totally the wrong approach. As stated [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/507e80e0-718e-4e31-ad1a-db82f684685d/special-permission-on-dbdatareader-user-for-execute-sphelptext?forum=transactsql&prof=required) by Jesus Lopez, if you want to give a user permissions to see all objects definitions, you must use

`GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO your_database_user`

or if you want to let a user see object definition for a particular object, you must use

`GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON dbo.YourProcedure TO your_database_user`.

Notice that firstly you must add an existing server [login](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx) as a new [user](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx) in the database. Then, you will be able to select the target database where the new user has been created, and then grant him/her permissions with `GRANT VIEW DEFINITION` statement.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is

```
Grant Execute on sp_helptext to user
```

and must be executed with master as the current database.

You can also do it through the GUI by right clicking on the user or the proc and going to properties. The exact steps depend on whether you are using enterprise manager or sql management studio.

Alternately add them to a role that has permissions on it already, public is the minimum required.

```
exec sp_addrolemember 'public', 'user'
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of the command needs to be

```
grant execute on sp_helptext to [DomainName\UserName] ;
```

Comment: That could fire `Permissions on server scoped catalog views or system stored procedures or extended stored procedures can be granted only when the current database is master.`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a sql guru but I would imagine the developers would also need read/execute permission to the stored procedure they are getting the text for.